# How to unlink multiple images with comma separated in database from the folder in php?

Tags: php, image

do any one know how to unlink multiple images which are stored with comma separated in database, like this,
[image]

so when i am going to unlink the image and remove the record i have used this code

```
$marketstatus = "SELECT * FROM $tb_online_exam_results_upload WHERE stu_id='$statuid' and exam_id='$exam_id' and term_id='$term_id'";
    $market_status_res=mysqli_query($conn,$marketstatus);
    if($market_status_res){
        $rows_online_exam = mysqli_fetch_assoc($market_status_res);
        $files = $rows_online_exam['uploads'];
                                    
        $images = explode(', ',$files);
        foreach($images AS $image){
            unlink("../../../upload_questions/'.$image.'");
        }
        $del = "DELETE FROM $tb_online_exam_results_upload WHERE stu_id='$statuid' and exam_id='$exam_id' and term_id='$term_id'";
        $res_del = mysqli_query($conn,$del);
      echo "Deleted Successfully";
    }
```

But in this way the record is getting deleted but the image is not unlinked or is not removed from the folder.

Comment: try: `unlink("../../../upload_questions/".trim($image));`

Comment: You should [normalize your database](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead of storing multiple values in one single column like that.

Comment: Thanks @Anant Singh---Alive to Die it worked for me, can you please answer it.

Comment: Hello @Dharman this is just a test purpose, i do prefer prepared statements...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First what @Magnus Eriksson says :  You should [normalize your database](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead of storing multiple values in one single column like that. Try to do this.
2. change your code like this: `unlink("../../../upload_questions/".trim($image));`

Note:- code change because I saw space in your column values (in image).Also less quotes can do the job as well.